# HP Pavilion DV6 6C00TU webcam not working

Tags: laptop, webcam, hp-pavilion

I just purchased HP Pavilion dv6 6C00TU 3 weeks ago and its webcam was working 100% perfectly. 3 days ago, I just downloaded a software named as **magic-ivisual** something. It is a software that shows some cartoon characters and those characters move same as the person using the laptop is moving.

Anyways, the problem is, after installing the magic-ivisual software, my webcam stopped working.
There is CyberLink YouCam installed in this laptop and when I open it up, it shows me this message:

**Warning:** no webcam detected. try plugging in a webcam into your computer now. if you are using an integrated camera, make sure that is turned on.[image]

***Solutions I have tried:***

**1** Un-installed the webcam and re-installed it

**2** Checking the drivers but could not find the Imaging section in my device manager

**3** Restarting my laptop many times, but nothing happened

**4** Tried camera using Skype, and www.neave.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your operating system is a recent version of Windows and you have a system restore point just before the date you installed the magic-ivisual program, you could restore to that point.

---

Start -> Control Panel -> Backup and Restore -> Create a restore point or change settings -> System Restore

Carefully choose a suitable restore point.

---

Windows 7 home edition examples for setting up and using system restore points. Other versions of Windows are slightly different.

[image: configuring system protection] [image: list of restore-points]

Comment: I am using windows 7 Basic Home Edition. How can I restore it from that point? I have updated my question as well.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I just created a restore point and nothing happened. I did not find any change in my system.

Comment: The link is named "create a restore point" but what you actually do is not create a new one but **restore** an existing point dated prior to the date the problem arose.

Comment: There is no other restore point other than the one I created last time. What can I do now ?

Comment: Backup data, check backup, check backup again, reinstall Windows, reinstall apps, restore data, enable restore points.

Answer (score 0):

Goto

RUN > type "devmgmt.msc"

Then in Device Manager, go to 
   VIEW > SHOW HIDDEN DEVICES
then,
   UNINSTALL the devices with YELLOW EXCLAMATION POINT

### REBOOT (without device attached)

INSTALL DEVICE DRIVER First (from CD or MSI/EXE file)
shutdown one more time.
Plug back the device (webcam).
Restart computer.

## This should help solve your problem for corrupted device driver.

Recommendation: 
Next time when you want to remove webcam, simply shutdown the PC and then remove the webcam (or, Printer, iPOD, Nook, any device). This little practice should prevent future 'AlkaSeltzer time' and your system will be happy as you will be.

Comment: There is no device with yellow exclamation mark.

Comment: Alternate way to remove (by means of disabling) a driver is to install AUTORUNS and observe driver in the Windows\System32 folder the file with SYS extension. Usually, graphic drivers are loaded when video card and other graphic device drivers are loaded. By disabling the specific driver for your **magic-ivisual** you can return to a pre-installation state. Please read on how AUTORUNS work, it can become your best buddy in solving so many of thePC problem, now and in the future.

http://www.filehippo.com/download_autoruns/